# Is a zero trust https reverse proxy possible?

Tags: web-hosting, https, security-certificate, reverse-proxy

I have a small home server and I'm currently just pointing my domain to my static IP address but I'd like to stop doing that but without the use of current reverse proxy services as I don't like them. I was thinking of using a VPS to run some sort of transparent https proxy (I and point that to my domain) but I realized that a bad actor with access to the VPS could generate a new SSL certificate and act as the server so:

Is there some way of mitigating this attrack, perhaps signing the certificate in a specific way so it's at least easy to detect the attack?
Or a different approach to this problem?

Comment: Why are ypu worried about an attacker getting access to the VPS[but not your actual server?]

Comment: It's because I was wondering if a true zero trust proxy is possible not if my server gets compromised, also I have physical access to my server and the admin tools are available through the local network and only for me, a VPS is not something I fully control at least in my eyes

Comment: I cant see how a full Zero trust proxy can be possible as it must always represent a man-in-the-middle.

Comment: While I think its crazy to worry about the security of the reverse proxy and not the origin server....there are many definitions of "zero trust" your use of the term not clear from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get somewhat towards this by getting a $$$ EV cert and publishing a CAA record so that that is the certifier that must be used - However if a CA decides to ignore CAA this wont help you.

You can also set up regular checks to see if the cert has changed.  I expect there are services that will offer this - or you can roll your own with a script or Nagios plugin.

That said, it would probably be better to harden the VPS so it is no less secure then the web server.